# multiple azure chatbots doesn't authenticate

Tags: azure, multi-tenant, credentials, azure-bot-service

I have an azure bot framework, type multitenant. It runs ok.
After that, I created another bot framework in he same resources group, I setted the ApplicationID and secret correctly, but when I run it, the emulator throws an error:

> status 400 The bot's Microsoft App ID or Microsoft App Password is incorrect.
> in despite I double checked and copied correctly the credentials.
> Also, my first bot still running well.
> Furthermore, when I publish, when I try to run it in "test in web chat" I'm getting the same error.
> I'm running out of ideas

I'm trying to run a second azure bot service in the same resurces group but it doesn't run.
What I'm expecting: the chatbot must to run with the credentials acoording configuration.

Answer (score 0):

> The bot's Microsoft App ID or Microsoft App Password is incorrect

- Verify if the Message Endpoint of the Bot configured correctly in the `Azure Bot=>Configuration=>Messaging Endpoint`.
- Regenerate **MicrosoftAppPassword** in `Azure Bot=>Configuration=>Manage Password`.

I have created two Azure Bots Multitenant within same resource group, Plan and a new Microsoft App ID for both the bots.

[image]

- Created two Azure App Services with same resource groups.
- Deployed Python Bot applications to the two Azure App Services.
- Configured Bots with Azure App Services.

**Bot 1:**

[image]

**Bot 2:**

[image]

- **Able to test both the Bots successfully:**

**Bot1:**

[image]

**Bot 2:**

[image]